# files and folder created by a user get ownership of a differnt user when created at specific location

Tags: server, permissions, virtualbox, ownership

I have a folder `/vagrant` which is owned by user vagrant who is in group vagrant.

then if I switch to user root or ansible user and create  a directory at `/vagrant` path.
it gets ownership of vagrant:vagrant

```
drwxrwx---  1 vagrant vagrant       0 Feb 19 08:46 etc
```

Since it was created by root I was hoping that it would be owned and in root group,
I tried the same with ansible user who is also part of vagrant group but even then
the user and group are vagrant as in case of root.
What I want is to be able to set any user own file or folder!

**Update:**

```
# ls -ld /vagrant
drwxrwx--- 1 vagrant vagrant 8192 Feb 19 08:46 /vagrant
```

so others doesnt have any rights but the ansible user is in the vagrant group.

Comment: ...and what is the output of `ls -ld /vagrant`?

Comment: @mikewhatever , I see the vagrant folder doesnt have permission set for others, so which is probably why but ansible user is in the vagrant group.